# How to write dictionary to computer and read it through different methods?

Tags: c#

Can you tell me why it does not work? I get an error. I tried using your method but it does not seem like it is working.

```
public void OnSignOut(int pin)
    {
        if (this.pin == pin && this.SignIn == true)
        {

            stopwatch.Stop();
            double elasped = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            stopwatch.Reset();
            this.total += elasped;
            MessageBox.Show("You have worked for " + elasped + " seconds." + " You have worked for " + this.total + " seconds in total.");
            this.SignIn = false;
            this.end = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
            this.log.Add(this.name + " worked for " + elasped + " seconds." + "\r\n" + "Total Time: " + this.total + " seconds" + "\r\n" + "Log in: " + this.start + "   Log out: " + this.end + "\r\n\r\n\r\n");
            this.logbook.Add(DateTime.Now, elasped);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.logbook);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\path.json", json);

        }

    }
    public double AddUp_Hours(DateTime start_date, DateTime end_date)
    {
    System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\path.json");
    this.logbook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary< DateTime, double> > (json);
        DateTime first = start_date;
        DateTime second = end_date;
        double sums = this.logbook.Where(x => x.Key > first && x.Key < second)
              .Sum(x => x.Value);
        return sums;
```

Comment: Sounds like a data storage/serialization or DB scenario, isn't it?

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to serialize the data. Alternatively you could use a local database like SQLite.

Comment: Do you have know how to do it?

Comment: I've given you enough information to research how to achieve what you want to do. I'm afraid I don't have time to show you how to do it.

Comment: I've done the research I don't understand it.

Comment: Are you assigning the result of ReadAllText, arn't you? string json = ReadAllText(@"D:\path.json");

Comment: I got it to work thank you!

Comment: Nice, Feel free to [accept](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You've said you get an error. It would be very helpful if you could tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options, depending on your needs regarding scalability, features, security, etc:

- use the app-settings as key-value storage: if you only very little data, no strings attached
- serialize your data to XML/JSON/Binary: if you have some more data, and value data portability
- use a light-weight file-based database storage like SQLite: if you have quite some data, need to do some basic reporting, etc.
- use a full-fledged database if you have a massive amount of data, intend to do reporting, load balancing, replication, and much more.

Assuming you look for a small-scale, low-bar data-storage solution: Try Serialization to JSON for a start

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dict2JsonSO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dictionary<DateTime, int> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
            dict.Add(DateTime.Now, 100);
            dict.Add(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), 10);

            //save
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\path.txt", json);

            //load
            string loadedJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\path.txt");
            Dictionary<DateTime, int> loaded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DateTime, int>>(loadedJson);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: This requires Newtonsoft.Json. Install it via NuGet.

Comment: Hey, I tried to do what you told me to do but it did not work. Do you think it is because I made a mistake or is it because your way is not possible?Take a look at my edit if you can :).

Comment: @Daniel Have you installed Newtonsoft.Json as noted?

Comment: Hold on, I think it may have worked.

Comment: WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\your\Desktop\storage.json") / ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\your\Desktop\storage.json") ?

Comment: Hey my friend, the text file is saved but when I try to access it I get "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value'"

Comment: See the update, read storage.json to string, then deserialize to your dict.

Comment: I still get the same thing. I don't understand why.

Comment: is the storage.json file actually written and the content present?

Comment: yes the json file is written.

Comment: Back to square one, if you copy the sample from above to a new console app, save, install Newtonsoft.Json via NuGet, build, and debug up to the line where the file gets loaded: what do you see, is the file content loaded to the string?

Comment: Yes your code works on console.

Comment: I am glad to hear that.. Since you have proved it works you should be able to apply it to your code.

Comment: Now I dont get an exception but it does not seem to read it.